# Button not working when restored using SharedPreferences

Tags: android

I have an app which inflates button views on a click of a button(Button A). The button views inflated work properly, executing the code in their onClick method.

Now to save the layout generated, I keep a count of number of times the Button A is clicked and save this value using SharedPreferences. In onCreate method I create a for loop for the number of times the Button A was clicked and re-inflate those buttons, thus generating the same layout that was on screen when the app was killed. Though now, the buttons generated in the onCreate method no longer function.

I hope I have made some sense. The problem, when the app is started again in future, it builds the layout as it was when the app was clicked, but the button views no longer function for the onCLick method.

Here's the code for reference:

MainActivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

EditText et;
String z, r;
LinearLayout ll;
SharedPreferences sp;
Button fb1;
int c=0;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    et=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.et);
    sp=getSharedPreferences("MY_PREFS", 0);
    if (sp.contains("counter")) {
        for (int i=1;i<=sp.getInt("counter", 1);i++) {
            cr();}
    }
    c=sp.getInt("counter", 0);

}
public void cr() {
    ll=(LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.ll);
    LayoutInflater li=getLayoutInflater();
    View vw=li.inflate(R.layout.infla, null);
    ll.addView(vw);
    fb1=(Button) vw.findViewById(R.id.btn);
    fb1.setId(c);
}
public void click(View v) {
    int z=v.getId();
    switch (z) {
    case (R.id.button):
        et=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.et);
        cr();
        et.setText("");
        c=c+1;
        break;
    }

    Editor e=sp.edit();
    //e.putString("check", r);
    e.putInt("counter", c);
    //e.putInt("id", c);
    e.commit();

    for (int i=0; i<=c;i++){
        if (z%2==0) {//Present
            et.setText("Present");}
        else if(z%2==1)
            et.setText("Absent");
        }
}
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}
}
```

activity_main.xml

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:id="@+id/ll"
tools:context=".MainActivity" >

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/et"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
    android:ems="10"
    android:hint="Enter something" >

    <requestFocus />
</EditText>

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
    android:onClick="click"
    android:text="Click" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="remove" />

</LinearLayout>
```

infla.xml

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<Button
    android:id="@+id/btn"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Button"
    android:onClick="click" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Edit:
You seem to have assigned redundant id's to the button during initialization.Each button would be assigned the value 'c' instead of 0 to 'c'.

Additionally It seems only logical to create click listeners on the fly as well ,since you are inflating button on the go.Try implementing the onclicklistener instead of the hardwired click() method in the xml.
i.e

```
public void cr() {
   ll=(LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.ll);
   LayoutInflater li=getLayoutInflater();
   View vw=li.inflate(R.layout.infla, null);
   ll.addView(vw);
   fb1=(Button) vw.findViewById(R.id.btn);
   fb1.setId(c);
   fb1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
 //Stuff you wish to do on click
   });
}
```

Comment: Its not working. I think its because everytime for the click listener to work, you will have to call the cr() method. Any other suggestions?

Comment: You're code suggests you are not assigning the id values properly  i.e in your onCreate() method all buttons created have the same value for id i.e 'c'.

Comment: Man!! Can't believe that was the mistake!! Thanks a ton!
PS- if you could just change your answer to the above so I can give it a green tick. Thanks again!!